# delete (free) elements from stringstream

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl

I'm trying to process a large amount of data. I have a `std::stringstream` which is initialized by a large buffer (about 0.5g) and i'm reading from it:

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), fileSize, infile);
std::stringstream stream(buffer);
free(buffer)
```

(the `buffer` is very large)
now I'm reading from this `std::stringstream` in the following manner:

```
while(std::getline(stream, line))
{
  do something with that line...
}
```

because this stream was initialized by a large buffer and I'm using STL containers to store that data from `line` inside this loop , I'm running out of memory.

is there a way to free bytes from the `std::stringstream` as I'm going through that parsing loop to free memory for the other containers I'm using later?

Comment: Just out of interest, why aren't you just using `std::fstream`?

Comment: because i wanted to import the file into memory and not reading it line by line so i chose to read it first into a buffer and then access it like a string stream

Comment: Sounds a little bit like premature optimisation to me ;) Was using `fstream` really too slow? My only other suggestions would be to consider low-level stuff like `mmap` or see about writing your own string buffer class which progressives disposes of itself when read from via the normal `istream` mechanism... but that seems like a lot of effort when you could just use `fstream`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) uses [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to store its data, the contents of `buffer` is *copied* to a string that is stored inside the stream. So to answer your question, yes you can free the buffer as soon as you created and initialized the string stream.

However, a more interesting question back to you is why you're using C file handling instead of C++ streams directly? And why read the whole file into memory, if it's so big, why not chunks of it (like one or more lines)? Or why not [memory map the file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) instead?

Comment: I'll answer your quenstions in a bit but my question was not if i can free the buffer , i know i can... my question was can i free parts from that stringstream after i read it into line

Comment: 1. I like the C-style file handling because I'm moving to c++ now from c so its leftovers from previous life :) 2.when i tried to read line by line it worked really really slow 3.I'm not familiar with that yet

Comment: @DimaShifrin Ah, then no you can't do that, because you don't own the buffer. And it's not possible to free parts of some memory. It might be possibly to get the string, and make a substring from the current position and set it in the stream buffer again, but that's more work than it's really worth. I really suggest you look at memory mapping of files, then you can read the file like a normal pointer, unfortunately you can't use the nice stream functionality (like `std::getline`) but it can in other ways be both simpler and more efficient.

Comment: memory mapping of files worked for me! and learned something new along the way , thanks!